# Even though assigned zero to variables yet I am getting error "cannot aasign to literal"

Tags: python

```
def car_type(m):
    ar=0,br=0,cr=0
    for i in m:
        if i=='sedan':
            ar+=1
        if i=='SUV':
            br+=1
        if i=='hatchback':
            cr+=1
    l.append(ar)
    l.append(br)
    l.append(cr)
    print(l)
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-7-c1c0dab37c53>", line 2
    ar=0,br=0,cr=0
      ^ SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: You cannot assign variables in a single line in python with comma. Its considered as a tuple, and in a tuple you cannot assign. Split your declarations to multilines

Comment: The error is telling exactly what the problem is. You can't assign to a literal like that. It should be `ar, br, cr = 0, 0, 0`

Comment: Or `ar = br = cr = 0` as well works.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to assign multiple variables in one line like you did.

**Correct syntax for multiple assignments in one line:**

```
ar, br, cr = 0, 0, 0
```

**If you want to assign the same values, you can use the following syntax:**

```
ar = br = cr= 0
```

**or just break it down into multiple lines:**

```
ar = 0
br = 0
cr = 0
```

Which version is better depends on the context and the meaning of the variables.